# Struts 1 Action Forward returns 404

Tags: javascript, xml, jakarta-ee, struts, web.xml

I have and index page with a button that needs to redirect to a confirmation page, using a forwarding action class. 
Yet the jsp that should show up when i click on the btn is not recognised for some reasons, and i keep getting the 404 page.

My index page has a form that contains a button :

```
<form name="myF" method="get">
    <table border="1">
        <caption>Gestion des etudiants STRUTS 1</caption>
        <tr>
            <td>Nom:<input type="text" name="nom"/></td>
            <td>Prenom:<input type="text" name="prenom"/></td>
            <td>Cin:<input type="text" name="cin" /></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Recherche Etudiant" onclick="recherche()"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

This javascript snippet links it with the struts controller

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
                function recherche(){
                    this.document.myF.action="rechercher.do";
                    this.document.myF.submit();
                }
    </script>
```

My struts config should send the data to the corresponding action class servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config 
PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.1//EN" 
 "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_1.dtd">

<struts-config>
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="etudiantForm"
            type="ecole.ensa.etudiant.presentation.forms.EtudiantForm">
            <form-property name="nom" type="java.lang.String" />
            <form-property name="prenom" type="java.lang.String" />
            <form-property name="cin" type="java.lang.String" />
        </form-bean>
    </form-beans>
    <action-mappings>

        <action path="/rechercher" input="/index.jsp" 
            type="ecole.ensa.etudiant.presentation.action.RechEtudiantAction">
            <forward name="success" path="/jsps/ajout_ok.jsp" />
        </action>
    </action-mappings>
</struts-config>
```

The action class is simply set to forward the view page:

```
public class RechEtudiantAction extends Action {

    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws Exception {

        return mapping.findForward("success");
    }
}
```

And for sanity check purposes, here is my web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
      <display-name>Etudiant</display-name>
  <!-- Servlet controleur de Struts -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>config</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <!-- Mapping des url avec la servlet -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- page d'accueil de l'application -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The result of my button click is always a 404 page, with the following url :
localhost:8080/Etudiant/rechercher.do?nom=&prenom=&cin=

None of the topics i browsed on internet seems to answer to my problem, and i'm clueless as to how to properly debug this kind of issue.

**UPDATE 1* :**
Usually i run tomcat with systemd.
This time i tried to start the server from eclipse, using the tomcat installation folder as server path /usr/share/tomcat8.
What i don't understand is why the index page shows up when i start the server from eclipse, but when i right click the project then press "run as server" on the same server, i get a 404 error ?

Comment: If you go to `http://localhost:8080/Etudiant/rechercher.do` directly from the browser does it work? Is `Etudiant` your web app context? Does `/jsps/ajout_ok.jsp` exist? (Unrelated, but in general, keep your JSPs under `WEB-INF` to disallow direct access from the client.)

Comment: 1/ http://localhost:8080/Etudiant/rechercher.do returns 404 when access it directly ; 2/ Yes ; 3/ /Yes it does ; Also the jsps folder is actually under WEB-INF, is it still allowing the client direct access ?

Comment: If the JSP is under web-inf then that needs to be in the JSP path in the action config.

Comment: Isn't it already the case when i put it in the forward as : <forward name="success" path="/jsps/ajout_ok.jsp" /> ?

Comment: I do not see the WEB-INF there's, so no. There's no magic: you need to specify the path to the JSP, including WEB-INF.

Comment: I changed the path as you mentioned, but the error persists. Some other topics i'm exploring evoke an incorrect html mapping. Apparently i should use taglibs in order to make it work. I tried but whenever i add the tlds in the WEB-INF, declare them in the index.jsp, and map them with the web.xml. I get an internal 500 error that i can't resolve either.

Comment: Then something else is wrong, likely in your Eclipse Tomcat setup.